# show shortcodes according to url

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to programming. Let's see if you can help me. I have to create a script to show several different short codes depending on the result of each url. They gave me this code but there's no way

```
<script>
var pages = window.location.href;
if((url == '/?listing_region=alicante')) { 
 echo do_shortcode( '[template id="11570"]' );
else  {
    if((url == '/?listing_region=madrid')) {
} echo do_shortcode( '[template id="11571"]' );
 else  {
    if((url == '/?listing_region=barcelona')) {
} echo do_shortcode( '[template id="11570"]' );

}</script>
```

Comment: Where did you define the variable ```url```?

Comment: I'm not sure how this script is supposed to work. What happens after the echo?

Comment: JS is executed client side while the PHP is executed server side. There is no way this code can work. Instead move all the code to PHP and use `$_GET['listing_region']` to check for the correct url part.

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing php tags before and after your individual `echo ....` calls. Your if / else setup is strange, as well. And, as Innovin mentioned, you're using the JS `url` variable, but you're not defining it anywhere. Should that be `page`, instead of `url`? Also, what should the `echo do_shortcode(....)` output, and should that happen in the JS part? Have you considered using `$_GET['listing_region']` and echoing the `do_shortcode(...)` based on that?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty lost
The idea is like this code that works for me but instead of the text to be able to show the short code, can it be done?`<script>switch ( 
window.location.href) 
{
   case "https://www.mywebsite.es/?listing_region=alicante":
      document.write("You are a good visitor<BR>\n")
      break 
   case "https://www.miwebsite.es/?location=madrid":
      document.write("You are a bad visitor<BR>\n")
      break
   default:
      document.write("You are ALIEN<BR>\n")
      break
}</script>`